# When is the difference of the "1" matrix and a positive semidefinite matrix positive semidefinite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider a [positive semidefinite matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-semidefinite_matrix#Positive-semidefinite) $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$. Let $E$ denote the matrix in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ all of whose entries are $1$.

> What are some natural sufficient conditions for $E-A$ to be positive semidefinite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $P=\frac{1}{n}E$, so $P$ is a rank-one orthogonal projection, and it suffices to consider when $P-A$ is positive semidefinite.  If $0\leq A\leq P$, then $A^{1/k}\leq P$ for all $k\geq 1$.  Letting $k\to \infty$, if $Q$ is the projection onto the range of $A$, then $Q\leq P$.  Since $P$ has rank 1, this means that $Q=P$ or $Q=0$.  This implies that $A=cP$ for some $c\in[0,1]$.  This necessary condition is also sufficient.

Comment: Thanks, Jonas. This is what I feared. (I keep wanting this to be nontrivial...and it never is!)